# SQL COUNT how many times a value appears

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, count

I have a database and I'm tasked to find out how many times the book
'Hood' has been borrowed. I know it's twice

[image: Given Database]

I have to write SQL to return how many times it was borrowed.
So far I have this but it only returns how many unique Books there are not how many times 'Hood' was borrowed

```
select count('Hood') as lenttimes
from
(
    select distinct bTitle from borrow
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is apply a `where` clause and count the results:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   borrow
WHERE  bTitle = 'Hood'
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want:

```
select sum(iff(btitle = 'Hood', 1, 0)) as lenttimes
from borrow;
```

This uses `sum(iff())` so you can count more than one title (in another column).

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, i understood your problem correctly.

Please check below query.

```
select count(0) from borrow where btitle='Hood'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return number of rows in your table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM borrow WHERE bTitle='Hood';
```